# How to compare dictionaries with a function in Python 3+

Tags: python, function, dictionary, code-snippets

I would like to compare dictionaries with a precise pattern inside a function.
My final goal is to:

- Incrementing by 3 the variable when 2 dictionaries have the same key and value
- Decrementing by -1 the variable if the value is not the same
- 0 if one pair of key/value is not present

for instance:

```
dict1 = {"EX1": "C", "EX2": "D", "EX4": "A", "EX5": "A"}
dict2 = {"EX1": "C", "EX2": "A", "EX3": "A", "EX4": "A", "EX5": "A"}
```

Expected output:

> 8

8 because:
-The EX1 key has the same value in both dictionaries(3)

-The EX2 key hasn't the same value in both dictionaries(3-1=2)

-The EX3 key is not present in the dict1 so no operation(2)

-The EX4 key has the same value in both dictionaries(2+3=5)

-The EX5 key has the same value in both dictionaries(5+3=8)

I got from the internet those two snippets that I don't know how to convert into a function I don't know if these can help:

```
{k : dict1[k] for k in dict1 if k in rep_valid and dict1[k] == rep_valid[k]} #Get same items
{k : dict2[k] for k in set(dict2) - set(dict1)} #Get difference
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to get the answer:

```
dict1 = {"EX1": "C", "EX2": "D", "EX4": "A", "EX5": "A"}
dict2 = {"EX1": "C", "EX2": "A", "EX3": "A", "EX4": "A", "EX5": "A"}

# (count matching keys)*3 - (count not matching keys)
ttl = len([k for k in dict1 if k in dict2 and dict1[k]==dict2[k]]) * 3 - len([k for k in dict1 if k in dict2 and dict1[k]!=dict2[k]])

print(ttl)  # 8
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following function which also supports nested dictionaries:

```py
def is_dict_equal(d1, d2):
    # for each key in d1
    for key in d1.keys():
        # check if d2 also has the key
        if key not in d2:
            return False

        value1 = d1.get[key]
        value2 = d2.get[key]
        if isinstance(value1, dict): # if the value is another dictionary call this function again
            if not is_dict_equal(value1, value2):
                return False
        elif value1 != value2: # else just compare them with eachother
            return False

    # check for keys in d2 but not in d1
    for key in d2.keys():
        if key not in d1:
            return False

    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
for key in (set(dict1.keys()) & set(dict2.keys())):
    if dict1.get(key) == dict2.get(key):
        count += 3
    else:
        count -= 1
print(f"count = {count}")

#count = 8
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.